# VB2010 Extract all recurring strings with A -B as start-stop of each string from source

Tags: regex, string, extract

I'm looking for way to extract "abc" from source where ABC will always start with "X" and will stop with "Y".

At this moment I'm using:

```
  Dim myString As String = source3RTB.Text
    Dim finalString As String = myString.Substring((myString.IndexOf("X")), (myString.IndexOf("Y") - myString.IndexOf("X")) + 1)
    source2RTB.Text = finalString

    sourceRTB.Text = myString.Trim(finalString)
```

But there is problem as above code only selecting first X and first Y...

Source is complicated set of lines (xxxx) regex is not working too well for it `(?<=X)(.*?)(?=Y)` is only working for small piece of source, when I try it on whole source it is not working (not sure if it is because of new line, or...)

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you using the `s` modifier ? This will make the dots also match new lines. Demo [with s](http://regex101.com/r/zS0jC7), [without s](http://regex101.com/r/vS7yV0).

Comment: Ok I found solution, simple I just doing it one by one cutting off 1st marker so on next run it will cut off extracted part and will go straight to 2nd part... And so on :)

Comment: Well if you want it that way go ahead, if you could provide the current regex you're using with some input and expected output, we could maybe help you more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This regex will capture the inner text between an `X` and `Y`

`(?:^|\s*?)\b(x(\w*)y)\b(?=\s*|$)`

[image]

The `\w*` can be replaced with whatever search you're looking for. If you're looking to match new lines with the `.*?` then you should use the `m` option with your regex command to allow `.` to match new line characters.

I would have further customized this solution if the OP would have included sample text.

## Groups

Group 0 gets the entire matching string including preceding spaces

1. gets the full string including open and close tags
2. gets the inner string of alphabetical charcters

## PHP Code Example

```
<?php
$sourcestring="I'am xlikelyy xupvotey photos of xkittensy on the internet.";
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s*?)\b(x(\w*)y)\b(?=\s*|$)/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  xlikelyy
            [1] =>  xupvotey
            [2] =>  xkittensy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xlikelyy
            [1] => xupvotey
            [2] => xkittensy
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => likely
            [1] => upvote
            [2] => kittens
        )

)
```